# Is adding and removing event listeners more efficient compared to not removing them at all?

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have a 'SWITCH BUTTON' and and a normal 'BUTTON'. 
If SWITCH BUTTON is switched on, then the NORMAL BUTTON is enabled.
Else if SWITCH BUTTON is switched off, then the NORMAL BUTTON is disabled.

Under this circumstances, is it more efficient to add and remove the event listener of the NORMAL BUTTON to release memory consumption when it is disabled?

For example:

```
public void sample() {
    Switch switchButton = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.sample_switch);

    switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        Button normalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sample_button);

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                normalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Some codes...
                    }
                });
            } else
                normalButton.setOnClickListener(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As stated in the question, there is only one switch button and one normal button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it does in fact save memory, it will be minimal and constant, and therefor only worth optimizing at a very late stage in the process of development. The eventListener does not cost performance while it is registered, and the little bit of memory it costs is negligible.

The reason why you can unregister events is because you do not want the button to be linked to this functionality. Disabling the button is used to prevent the button from activating its linked functionality. It's a nuance, and in front-end development you'll never unregister a button from an event for a user not to click a button.

To answer your question, yes it will probably save the littlest tiniest bit of memory, but since it is only one button, the scale of optimization the unregistering will bring is not mentionable.